# \n (new line) not working in creating text file

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, download

I want to download the text file by clicking on button, everything is working fine as expected. But the problem is the data I want to insert in text file is just one line.

String fileContent = "Simple Solution \nDownload Example 1";
here, \n is not working. It resulting in output as:

```
Simple Solution Download Example 1
```

Code snippets:

interface:

[image]

interface implementation in my service class:

[image]

controller:

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Comment: On Windows end of line consists of two characters, "\r\n"

Comment: I don't know how to do this myself, but you're better keeping the `\n` only but writing to the file as text, not binary, otherwise Linux and Mac users will be complaining about an extra `\r` when they write.

Comment: From my office I cannot see your code, please post code as code not as external link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use hardcoded `\n` nor `\r\n` - line-separators are platform-specific (Windows differs to all other OS).

What you can do is:

1. Use `System.lineSeparator()`
2. Build content with `String.format()` and replace `\n` with `%n`

Comment: I've to deploy an application on my Linux env so I've used System.lineSeparator(); otherwise, \r\n working fine on windows.
Thanks for recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the server computer and client computer are basically independent with respect to character set encoding and line separators.
Defaults will not do.

1. As we are living in a Windows centric world (I am a linuxer), user `"\r\n"`.
2. Then java can mix any Unicode script. A file does not have info on its encoding.
   If it originates on an other computer/platform, that raises problems.

   ```
    String fileContent = "Simple Solution façade, mañana, €\r\n"
        + "Download Обичам ĉĝĥĵŝŭ Example 1";
   ```

   So the originating computer explicitly define the encoding. It should not do:

   ```
    fileContent.getBytes(); // Default platform encoding Charset.defaultCharset().
   ```

   So the originating computer can do:

   ```
    fileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // UTF-8, full Unicode.
    fileContent.getBytes("Windows-1252); // MS Windows Latin 1, some ? failures.
   ```

   The **contentType** can be set appropriately with `"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"` or for Windows-1252 `"text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1"`.

   And from that `byte[]` you should take the `.length` for the **contentLength**.
3. Writing to the file can use [Files.writeString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...))

   In that case use `Files.size(exportedPath)` for the content length.
4. `Files.newInputStream(exportedPath)` is the third goodie from Files.